# even after apt-get update E: Unable to locate package php5-memcached

Tags: php, memcache

I received a error

```
"PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcache' not found in "
```

so I tried to install memcache using the following command

```
"sudo apt-get install php5-memcache"
```

but it throws the following error

> E: Unable to locate package php5-memcache

I run sudo apt-get update, but it shows the same error.

Comment: You might want to first search for the package with `apt-cache search memcached | grep php` and then pick the one you need.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com might be a better place for such questions. PHP 5.x is no longer supported, so you should review what version you are using and upgrade if needed.